# jQuery fancy product designer - Change element color depend on first layer add

Tags: jquery, colors, product, designer

I am using jQuery fancy product designer, we can set element `color` with element parameter. What I have do to is that when user add any new element it should have default `color` same as chosen by user for 1st element.

Can we change it in `addElement` function?
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Can you provide the code you wrote please ?

Comment: http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/fancy-product-designer-jquery/full_screen_preview/3581183?_ga=1.171602985.829918024.1484222384


Lets say I add one design on t-shirt and change its color. If now i am adding 2nd one then it should have same color which I set for 1st one.

Comment: It would be nice to you to provide the code you wrote by updating your question.

You can also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

When user adds the new element, just check if he has added the element earlier. If found, get the color of it and change the color of currently added element.

```
elements.set("fill",fillColor);
```